# MacBook Pro does not recognize external, non-Apple devices (bluetooth, USB-c)

Tags: bluetooth, external-disk

I am a new Mac user (MacBook Pro 13''). The issue I am facing is that it seems I cannot pair any non-Apple external device to my computer.

In particular, I tried with:

- JBL wireless headphones, supposed to connect via bluetooth (on my iPhone I could connect via bluetooth)
- An external drive from Verbatim, connected via USB-c port

I believe it has something to do with my Mac not allowing external providers to connect? I guess some change is needed from settings side?

I would appreciate any suggestion on this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What filesystem is the external drive formatted with?  Does the drive appear in the USB tree displayed in System Information?

Comment: Restart the computer, reset SMC (system management controller), and if all else fails, reset entire machine with new macOS.

Comment: This really is 2 questions. Pairing bluetooth devices is very different to connecting a USB disk. What have you tried with the JBL headphones? There are lots of articles on the web about pairing JBL with Macs (and other computer).  I assume you have them in pairing mode and are using the Bluetooth System Preferences on the MBP.

Comment: support your headphones multipoint? Otherwise you have to unpair them from your iPhone first, then pair them with the MacBook.

Comment: regarding the external Verbatim drive: what type, even better model? Are you using a hub?

Answer (score 2):

The underlying assumption in your question is that Macs somehow do things differently for Apple devices as compared to non-Apple devices. That's not the case.

There's no setting to "allow external providers", simply because there's nothing in macOS that will "block" or "not allow" products from other vendors.

In particular, USB-C storage drives from any manufacturer should work well on the Mac, and Bluetooth headphones from any manufacturer should also work well on the Mac.

Regarding your Bluetooth headphones: Find the manual for the headphones and find out how to make them enter pairing mode. Usually this is done by holding one or more buttons on the head phones until an LED is blinking. Then open System Preferences > Bluetooth on your Mac and hopefully the device should appear in the list for you to connect with.

Regarding your external storage device not pairing. There's no pairing process for external storage devices. If you plug the device in it should automatically do the right thing. If you do not see a volume appear in Finder, it is must probably because the disk format is not supported by macOS.

You can open the app Disk Utility (comes with the Mac) to see all the volumes on your external disk. It will also allow you to reformat your external disk into a format that is supported by macOS - such as for example APFS (most commonly when only using the disk with Macs) or ExFAT (most commonly when sharing the disk between Mac and Windows systems).

Note that reformatting your disk means that the data stored on the disk is lost.

If you rather keep the format already there, you can install install third party file system drivers for some other types of file systems.